# Local variable returned in recursive function

Tags: c, recursion, fibonacci

i have written a  code for a fibonacci series returning the sum of the complete series, can the local "static int" variable be returned to the main function where the code is trying to print the sum.

Below is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>


int fiborecur(int n)
{
    static int first=0,second=1,sum=0,total=0;
    if( n>0 )
    {
        sum = first + second;
        total = total + sum;
        printf("  %d", sum);
        first = second;
        second = sum;
        fiborecur(n-1);
    }
    else
    {
        return total+1;
    }
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("Enter the series length you want = ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("0  1");
    printf("\nSum of the series after return = %d\n", fiborecur(n-2));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you are not returning a `static int`, you are returning its value, so yes. but this looks like it will fail on a second invocation, since nothing resets the statics

Comment: you can return without recursive function it will work fine..  Do you need with recursive function?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your problem is that you only return the total if `n == 0`, but your main function actually calls it with `n > 0`. Make your function always return `total + 1`, not only when n is zero (in other words just remove the `else`),  and it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Why are your int values declared as static?  Use your return value to return the current total, and then it will happen automatically.

Static values plus recursion is a recipe for disaster.